# How to use int index to read DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a DataFrame and am trying to iterate over it and process rows/series in batches of 3.

Passing an integer index to `dataFrame.iloc[]` returns the error

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

This works:

```
for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():
    dataFrameCopy.at[index, 'bullish_swing'] = classify_bullish_swing(dataFrameCopy.iloc[index,:], dataFrameCopy.iloc[index + 1,:], dataFrameCopy.iloc[index + 2,:])
```

This does not work:

```
for index in range(len(dataFrame) - 2):
    dataFrameCopy.at[index, 'bullish_swing'] = classify_bullish_swing(dataFrameCopy.iloc[index,:], dataFrameCopy.iloc[index + 1,:], dataFrameCopy.iloc[index + 2,:])
```

What I find confusing is that the index variable reportedly has the same type in both examples when `print(type())` is used. It also has a value of 0 when the error is thrown.

Stack trace:

```
dataFrameCopy.at[index, 'bullish_swing'] =
classify_bullish_swing(dataFrameCopy.iloc[index,:],
dataFrameCopy.iloc[index + 1,:], dataFrameCopy.iloc[index + 2,:])     
return super().__setitem__(key, value) self.loc
iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
empty_value[indexer[0]] = arr
```

Comment: Will you please add the whole stack trace? What you have provided is not very helpful.

Comment: Is your index of type int? Maybe try `.iloc` for the second code snippet, instead of `.at`.